# templateUrl is ot working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this angular directive

```
myModule.directive('ctt', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'hallo.html'
    };
});
```

But templateUrl is not working. When I use template it works fine. The file hallo.html is also in the right place.
What can I do to bring is to work?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: can we have html code, where you added directive and project structure ?

Comment: I bet the file hallo.html isn't in the right place, check the debug console for errors

Comment: Do you really have `hallo.html`? Not `hello.html`?

Comment: Yes i have a file called hallo.html in the root folder.

index.html
hallo,html
app\controller.js

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing the file locally [not using any server] in any browser other than Mozilla you will get error of crossdomain issue. If you open the local file in Mozilla you will not face any issue. Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I'am run the file on my local workstation.